# How could I execute a c code from an outer .txt file?

Tags: c, file, game-development

I am making a small sokoban game and I would like to load in the level setup from an outer txt file, but I'm new to file management. How Could I execute a c code from an outer txt file?

Comment: You could run the program from a script file, which passes setup information as program arguments. For example `sokoban level=3`

Comment: "*How Could I execute a c code from an outer txt file*" - the content of the outer file shouldn't be C code, but just a configuration that your C code program will parse and use.